# Application works on android 2.2, but not on 2.3

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I wanna write a kind of camera application which uses real-time preview from camera displayed on SurfaceView, another layer above preview is a mask (funny picture etc.). The function to take a picture on display click. The issue is that the application works on adroid 2.2 just fine but does NOT work on 2.3 (using phone and emulator). I have premission for camera in Mainfest.

Here is my activivty:

```
package funny.camera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity{

    private CamScreen cam;
    private LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    View touchscreen;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cam = new CamScreen(this);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 

        setContentView(R.layout.camscreen);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(cam);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);     

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());

        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camoverlay, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
        View viewTouch = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camtouch, null);
        addContentView(viewTouch, layoutParamsControl);  

        viewControl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cam.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });
    }
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {

        }};

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        }};

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {

        }};
}
```

And the classrelated to the camera preview

```
public class CamScreen extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    //SurfaceHolder sHolder;
    //SurfaceView surfaceView;
    Camera camera;

    CamScreen(Context context) {
    super(context);    
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Open the camera and start viewing    
        camera = Camera.open();

        try {
           camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Kill all our crap with the surface
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Modify parameters to match size.
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        camera.setParameters(params);

        camera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong? I thought taht if application works on older android version it works on the new one as well.

Thank you

Comment: Exactly what part does not work? No overlays? Crash?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

The API level 9 has public static Camera open (int cameraId)
where cameraid define the front and rear camera. please change the android jar for api level and change the method public  Camera.open () to  Camera open (int cameraId)

Comment: even using the higher API and Camera.open(cameraId) does not prevent application from crashing. Moreover, shouldn't camera.open() in API lvl 9+ open back-facing camera by default?

Comment: have you debugged your or at which point of line your application is crashing ............

Comment: After changing the API on higher level the application works on the emulator but keep falling in a phone

Comment: then have you checked you are adding required permission in your manifest or do check might your phone have some technical problem ,do check the same apps on other .......